Linking Graphviz to Protege Ontology Builder
I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.4 and trying to get Protege Ontology OWL visualiser to work correctly. Currently it scrunches up the ontology into the top left hand corner
On windows, I download the graphviz file package and link the OWLviz tool with the dot.exe file. However I'm unable to locate the dot.exe file in the linux file package.
Does anyone know what file i'm looking for/where I can get the dot.exe file needed?

"exe" is a Windows thing. Do you mean you are looking for the relevant exectable? How do you launch this tool? From some menu? Can you right click there and look at properties? Do you run from the command line? What is the "graphviz file package"? How do you "link it" in Windows? Please [edit] your question and clarify what you need.

Hi terdon, I can run the protege tool from a menu (it's an executable contained in a folder).
The graphviz file package was an install (sudo apt-get install graphviz) saved in the usr bin folder, but this only contains "dot.so" files.
To link the tool to the graphviz file package, I go into the tools preferences, and set the file path to the "dot" file

I think it might simply be that the software was made for windows/mac but not linux. I'lll see if I can sort the issue though use of a dual OS

I doubt it. It's an academic tool and such ontologies are very common in bioinformatics and the vast majority of bioinformaticians would use Linux, maybe Mac, but not Windows, it lacks too many basic tools. If you edit and add more detail we might be able to hellp.

Does this answer your question? How to install pydot and graphviz? "exe" is a Windows thing. Do what the accepted answer says to do and you're ready to go.

Hi both, Thank you for you follow up comments. I've done some checking. The specific tool is called Protégé, an ontology building software. I'm not able to locate the needed file for the system. I believe it's a compatible issue with Linux; it's needs a dot.exe file which is present in the windows download but not present in the linux download.
